# Windows 11 pro and kestrel - any easy way to setup friendly name for local ip address?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 Pro machine and I'm running the Kestrel web server on it to run a small web app for local network. The clients are iPads on the network. Is there any easy way to give the IP address a friendly name just for local network?

Comment: Have you got a DNS server on the network? Maybe your router lets you add DNS entries. Or is this in an office setting?

Comment: "Is there any easy way to give the IP address a friendly name just for local network?" - You would have to configure the devices to use a custom name server, that is aware of the local servers, to accomplish this goal as there is no way to modify a host file on the device in question.

Comment: Does Windows 11 have a DNS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most home networks, you should be able to add DNS records somewhere in your router's configuration. These just map a name like `FriendlyName` to your windows PC's IP address `192.168.x.y`

---

Even if there is no DNS service or you don't have access to one, the iPads should be able to resolve the hostname of the windows 11 PC through Bonjour/mDNS/NetBIOS. This usually looks like `http://DESKTOP-1234ABC.local/` or `http://DESKTOP-1234ABC/` for example (You would need to rename the PC to change the friendly name).

This should be enabled by default when the windows 11 PC's network is set to [Private](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d#WindowsVersion=Windows_11) vs "Public"

---

Most webservices will need to have that hostname added to their binding settings. It looks like Kestrel [ignores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33198152/7411885) host names though, so that should not be an issue for you